# Duplicates on apex function call with apex repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I have a below apex function call

```
<apex:actionFunction name="searchContinueAvailableSlotJS" action="{!searchnextSevenSlots}" status="searchOpenSlots" onComplete="Appointment.onContinuationComplete()" rerender="confirmMsgPanel,nextSevenDaysId"/>
```

On Above call I rerender the components with id nextsevendays. Now this component has a apex:repeat which has a Map in it and that map gets updated on every apex function call. and I recurrsively calling the apex function 4 times like below from a javascript function

```
function1 () {
if(counter < 4){
searchContinueAvailableSlotJS();
}
}
```

Now this creates duplicate values on the UI as below. 
After first call say Map has value1 
After second call map has value1 , value 2 
so on UI it displays duplicate values 
Value 1
Value 1
Value 2
Value 1 
Value 2 
Value 3 ..... and so on. 
Can someone suggest a way to overcome this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think for each counter you are adding values in the map. Here I am thinking it is not simple as Value 1, Value 2....kind of simple values, rather it may have list of values.

So, let's say you are passing values in `lstString`, for each iteration it may be specific set of values (e.g. Value 1 on first iteration, Value 2 in 2nd iteration.

```
//first call
List<String> lstString = new List<String>();
lstString.add('Value 1');

//hold value values in the map
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();

//loop through list of values before putting into map, let's say you want to put 'Value 1' in the map
for(String outerStr:lstString)
{
    for(String str:myMap.keySet())  //compare with the key
    {
        List<String> lstInternalString = myMap.get(str); //get list of values already exist in the map
        String str2 = String.join(lstInternalString,','); //create a string with comma delimited way.
        if(!str2.contains(outerStr))                    //check 'Value 1' exists in the map.
        {
            //add value to the map
            myMap.put(str, lstInternalString.add(outerStr));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am putting unique values and map has unique values I checked it. But since apex action function is re rendering the section it duplicates the values while displaying.

Comment: I have given a direction how to handle it, since you didn't share your full code, thats why I have assumed and written this code.